# Get id from clicked table row and show values of that row

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a history on my site and I want to get the values from the clicked row and show them only for that row id. I have [image: this] table but when I click in each row it shows the same values for different rows like [image: this]

HTML code:

```
<table style="width:100%" id="listagem">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;">Data</th>                           
    <th style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;">Sala</th> 
    <th style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px;">Tipo</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ocorrencia` as o ORDER BY 
o.data DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)): ?>
    <tr id="tr" onclick="hide(), window.location = '#bg'">
        <td idlista="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" style="display:visible;font-family: 
Arial; font-size: 12px;"><a><?php echo $row['id']; ?></a></td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['data']; ?> 
</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?> 
</td>
        <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 17px;">
<?php
$result_t = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT m.tipo 
                            FROM `material` as m 
                            INNER JOIN `ocorrencia_detalhe` as od on m.id = od.id_tipo 
                                AND od.id_ocorrencia=".$row['id']);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_t)): ?>
    <?php echo $row2['tipo'] . " "; ?>
<?php endwhile;?>                                       
</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here is the js code:

```
var idocorrencia;
$(document).on("click","#listagem tr", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    idocorrencia = $(this).parent().attr("idlista");
    $("#listagem caption").text($(this).text());
    $.post( "historico.php", { idoc: idocorrencia })
});
```

And here is the php code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
$idoc = isset($_POST['idoc']) ? $_POST['idoc'] :  1;                        
echo  $idoc;
$query =  "SELECT * FROM ocorrencia where id=$idoc";
echo $query;
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);                     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)): ?>
    <p class="data"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></p>
    <p class="sala"><?php echo $row['sala']; ?></p>
    <textarea readonly id="descricao"><?php echo $row['descricao'];?></textarea>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: WHat is the point of the first query and while loop? If user does not pass a parameter in `$_POST` then just return an error message

Comment: How many rows are there in the `ocorrencia` table?

Comment: _DEBUGGING - Step One:_ Does the Javascript actually pass a value to the PHP script?

Comment: `#listagem tr` listagem is an ID of tr?

Comment: I think we are going to need to see the HTML that this javascript is processing if you want us to be of any help to you

Comment: listagem is the table id

Comment: show your table html in your question ...

Comment: I have edited all the question

Comment: I think you need to review what an [anchor tag `<a>` is for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: You are giving a `<tr>` an `id` in a loop! `id's` are supposed to be Unique in a page!

Comment: `<td idlista="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ` the `<td>` element does not have an `idlista` attribute!

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: that is not the problem because when I click on the row it shows an alert with that id